# Problema de fondos con Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

tengo una pregunta, tengo una imagen que quiero poner de fondo, y luego mas imagenes encima de esa foto, que la quiero como fondo. (para meter en contexto, quiero una imagen que sea de fondo, que es el escenario de un combate pokemon, y, encima poner los sprites de pokemon) mi pregunta es, es capaz de hacerse tal cosa? o deberia cambiar a pygame? (me gustaria no hacerlo, porque soy novato y no se casi nada de pygame.)

```
    ventana.title("Combate Pokemon")
    ventana.geometry('800x700')
    ventana.resizable(0, 0)

    fondo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'Campo_de_batalla_DPPt_2.png'))
    Pokemon1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'golem.png'))

    label = Label(image=fondo)
    label1 = Label(image=Pokemon1)
    label.pack()
    label1.pack()
```

Comment: ¿ Quieres hacer un juego ? si es así pygame es lo que necesitas

Comment: gracias por si recomendacion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer un videojuego será mejor y más fácil una librería dedicada a ello.

Pero por si acaso, te dejo un pequeño codigo simple de como se haría en tkinter, haciendo uso del canvas. Canvas nos permite realizar figuras sobre él o superponer imágenes entre otras cosas.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, PhotoImage

app = Tk()
app.geometry("280x180")

#highlightthickness=0 para eliminar los bordes del canvas
canvas = Canvas(app, width=280, height=180, background="white", highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

img_bg = PhotoImage(file="campo_batalla.png")
img_pokemon1 = PhotoImage(file="pikachu.png")
img_pokemon2 = PhotoImage(file="pokemon2.png")

bg_tag = canvas.create_image(50,50, image=img_bg)
pokemon_tag = canvas.create_image(170,50, image=img_pokemon1)


#PODEMOS DAR FUNCIONALIDAD AL JUEGO, SIENDO ESTO UN EJEMPLO:
def cambiar_img(event):
    canvas.itemconfig(pokemon_tag, image=img_pokemon2)

def mover_izquierda(event):
    canvas.move(pokemon_tag, -10,0)

#Cuando se presiona espacio la imagen cambia a otra
app.bind("<space>", cambiar_img)
#Cuando se presiona intro la imagen se mueve -10p a la izquiera
app.bind("<Return>", mover_izquierda)

app.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mas funciones y configuraciones consulta: https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/canvas.html

Espero haberte ayudado :)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda, de momento usare su codigo para entregar el trabajo, pero la idea es hacer un combate por turnos lo mas fiel posible a pokemon, aun asi, le doy las gracias de nuevo por su ayuda!

Comment: He editado la respuesta para que puedas ver como podrías darle funcionalidad. Suerte con el juego!! Soy nuevo aquí, así que creo que me ayudaría si aceptaras la respuesta si te ha servido :)